# How can I obtain the original URL that [Authorize] redirected to login page from?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

In my configuration method, I have the following

```
...
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/home/login");
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

When I decorate a method with *[Authorize]*, I get redirected to */home/login*. However, I'd also like the user to be sent back to where they came from and in order to do that, I need to pass the origin to the login page like this.

```
...
string origin = ???
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/home/login?origin=" + origin);
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

Is is possible to obtain *origin* somehow there or is my call to *UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects* poorly suited? How should I approach it?

Comment: Iam using returnUrl in url and in login method redirect to that url if login success. It may help https://forums.asp.net/t/2116585.aspx?How+to+get+return+url+in+asp+net+core+

Comment: @daremachine Oh, you mean I have to inherit the class? I was hoping on a solution that let me configure that without inheritance. Nevertheless, overriding lets me control other details the way I like, so it might be a good idea anyway. When the conditions for user/pass are met, you just set the cookie somehow, right?

Comment: Login redirects include a `returnUrl` query param out of the box. Nothing your need to do. You can customize this param to be something like `origin` instead, if you like, though. `UseStatusCodePages` is for handling things like 404s, not login redirects.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Good hint, thanks. So the way I did is something I **can do** but perhaps not **should do**, right? Is the recommended way to inherit the class *Authorize*?

Comment: No. `AuthorizeAttribute` is different in Core. It's mostly a placeholder for applying external auth logic, policies, etc. It has nothing in worth overriding and thus no reason to inherit from it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for the heads-up. I was led to (incorrect) impression that it was the way to go (probably older blogs/questions). So I should rely on *services.AddAuthentication(...)* and configure *AddJwtBearer*? I'm building MVC app and not SPA, if it matters...

Comment: There's authentication and there's authorization. The Authorize attribute triggers both. In it's base form it just ensures users are authenticated, but if you specify roles or policies that's where authorization comes into play.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187606/discussion-between-konrad-viltersten-and-chris-pratt).

Answer (score 2):

first, set up your startup class as shown below

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        //-----
        services.AddAuthentication(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        ).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";

                // The ReturnUrlParameter determines the name of the query parameter 
                // which is appended by the handler
                // when during a Challenge. This is also the query string parameter   
                // looked for when a request arrives on the 
                // login path or logout path, in order to return to the original url  
                // after the action is performed.
                options.ReturnUrlParameter=origin;//the default value is returnUrl

            });
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme =CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });
        //----
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

AccountController

```
    public IActionResult Login(string origin)
    {
        //save original url
        ViewBag.Origin = origin; 
        return View();
    }

    //get the original url from hide input
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        //if (login successfull)
        //{
            return Redirect(model.Origin);
        //}
        // else
        //{
            return View(model);
        //}
    }
```

Comment: In your suggestion, it's authorized by a cookie. I'd like to use tokens, like JWT. Do you have a suggestion on how to configure services then?

Comment: Also, I wonder how come you add authentication to the services twice. Is there something I'm missing? It seems to me like you configure the authentication including adding a cookie and then, again, add an authentication without adding a cookie. Please explain.

Comment: @KonradViltersten The answer I provided is based on MSDN documentation. Please refer to the relevant documentation for a better understanding. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've seen the link before and I also took time to read through the article again. Still, I fail to see where the repeated invocation of *AddAuthentication* comes from. Please advise.